# Semantic UI fade in/out transitions

Tags: html, semantic-ui

The docs for Semantic UI do provide a link for [transitions](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/transition.html) but it is missing an entry for `'fade in'` and `'fade out'` effects. Are they on future versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not explicitly mentioned in the documentation, all animations in Semantic UI can use the modifiers `in` or `out` to force the animation to be inward or outward.

```
// Will fade out the leaf if it's visible, otherwise fades in.
$('.autumn.leaf').transition('fade');

// Will always fade in the leaf. If it's visible, it will first hide it immediately, then fade it in.
$('.autumn.leaf').transition('fade in');

// Will always fade out the leaf. If it's hidden, it will first show it immediately, then fade it out.
$('.autumn.leaf').transition('fade out');
```

I'd personally recommend you avoid them - you should instead be aware of the element's current visibility and just use the normal `fade` transition:

```
// Only fade in the leaf if it's hidden, otherwise do nothing.
if ($('.autumn.leaf').hasClass('hidden')) {
    $('.autumn.leaf').transition('fade');
}
```